# How to find the number of zero points of a function within a given parameter range?

Tags: functions

```
f[x_] = x E^x + 1/2 - E^x + x^3/3 - k x^2
```

Given the function f (x), find the number of zero points of the function when the parameter k is greater than or equal to 0

Comment: Ask it at MSE since your  question is math, not Mathematica. As far as I know it, Mathematica and Maple have no special tools to this end.

Comment: How do you the calculation if the parameter `k=0`?